# Visual studio Code forcing brackets on oneline if

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, code-formatting

I use VS Code on Linux Mint 18.

It wraps one line commands with brackets. How can I stop that behavior?

e.g.

```
if (1)
echo 'Hi!';
```

becomes

```
if(1)
{
    echo 'Hi!';
}
```

I don't like that. It's annoying. Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the linter. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php#_linting for more info.

Looks like you can just add `"php.validate.enable": false` to your settings if you want to disable it.

Comment: You added this to your user settings?

Comment: Tried adding that to settings with no effect. But I forgot to mention that I use phpfmt addon for code formatting. It seems there are no settings available. What do you recommend